# OPTION (MAXDOP) with sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT [SomeColumn]
FROM [Table1] t1 
WHERE Table1ID = (
        SELECT [Table1ID]
        FROM [Table2] t2 
        WHERE t2.ID = 2
        OPTION (MAXDOP 4)
        )
OPTION (MAXDOP 4)
```

This gives an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.` on the first `OPTION (MAXDOP)`
Is it possible to use `OPTION (MAXDOP`) in a sub query? Or the final `OPTION (MAXDOP)` will be good enough to set the degree for the sub query as well.

Comment: Final OPTION(MAXDOP) is enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The subquery might not be in one piece at runtime. The optimizer can pick it apart and reorder everything. This query will certainly not execute as written. Therefore a maxdop for a subquery does not apply to SQL Servers execution model.

There can only be one maxdop for the whole query. There is a logical reason for this restriction.

Comment: Right, you have to put maxdop statement after the "last outer" query

Comment: "There is a logical reason for this restriction", but I'm not going to tell you :-P

Comment: @Thronk it took 2 years for someone to become interested enough to ask :) The reason is that the optimizer can transform the query completely away from its written form. It's really hard to specify a subpart of a query with certain settings given this kind of total reorganization model.

Comment: @usr - Thank you.  I still upvoted the answer, and actually knew that was the case, but I couldn't resist the sarcastic crack.  :-)